# Angular: How to route to a whole new page instead of injecting it in <router-outlet></router-outlet>?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I want to create a html page where the header is different than on most of my pages. Currently I have been injecting the content through `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` so the header and footer is always the same. How would I make the router just look at the components html that is connected to the routing instead of injecting it into the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` place

Comment: What does `make the router just look at the components html that is connected to the routing` mean ?

Comment: "How would I make the router just look at the components html that is connected to the routing instead of injecting it into the <router-outlet></router-outlet> place" What do you mean here? I am sure that's what the router is currently doing right? it looks at components connected to the routing

Comment: You should use the child routing concept on this type of scenarios, Need to change your routing structure

Comment: Just put the <router-outlet>  outside of your element with headers and footers.

Answer (score 1):

In your app component.html, you should have :

```
<body>
  <app-header></app-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</body>
```

You create app-header and app-footer component obviously.
If you want a special behavior in your header, you implement the behavior inside your component.

If your special header is completely different and does not share any logic with your app-header component, you can create a new one and display it conditionally such as :

```
<body>
  <app-header *ngIf="!condition"></app-header>
  <app-special-header *ngIf="condition"></app-special-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</body>
```